# Парсер, порции контента

Tags: php

Стоит задача сделать парсер. Использую simple_html_dom.php для dom.
Подскажите, допустим если сильно большой документ, с которого нужно парсить, как нужно сделать, чтобы парсинг был частями в цикле? т.е. чтобы не сильно тратились ресурсы.
допустим такой код:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://test.ru/sitemap.xml');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$dom = str_get_html($result);
foreach ($dom->find('loc') as $url) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: а зачем вообще для `XML` юзать `HTML DOM`, тем более еще и для больших? и сколько это большой 1мбайт, 10, 100, гигабайт?

Comment: @teran, а как правильно тогда парсить xml?
Дело в том, что начальные адреса, по которым нужно парсить берутся из sitemap.xml, а потом уже на основе полученных ссылок парсить html.
Мне поставили задачу парсить частями, только не знаю как это сделать.

Comment: ну таки с XML работают с помощью [XML-парсеров](http://php.net/manual/ru/refs.xml.php), там есть два подхода, DOM модель с полной загрузкой файла и SAX-модель, которая читает файл последоватльно не загружая его целиком в память, что критично при работе с большими файлами.

Comment: @teran, а если нужно парсить и xml и html, подойдёт для этого simple_html_dom.php ? Мне не только xml нужно парсить!
Как тогда последовательно загружать данные с помощью simple_html_dom.php ?

Comment: т.е. допустим внешний цикл проходит по xml, доставая ссылки, потом во внутреннем цикле нужно проходить по html

Comment: А вы какие ресурсы имеете ввиду и что значит не сильно тратились. Как бы процессорного времени все равно потребуется ровно столько, сколько потребуется. Если не нужны пики видимо надо что бы программа могла отдыхать и ничего не делать какое то время, но разбор при этом будет происходить гораздо медленнее. А если критична память то учится читать документ частями

Comment: а можете дать ссылку, где про это написано подробно, т.е. чтение документа частями? Я точно не знаю, как это правильно называется

Comment: и если вы читаете сначала список ссылок, а потом каждую из них отдельно обрабатываете вот оно само сабой и получается частями. вы же не будете сначала загружать все ссылки а потом только их разбирать

Comment: >вы же не будете сначала загружать все ссылки а потом только их разбирать

Comment: а есть какая-то разница в том, загрузить все ссылки, и потом по одной читать в цикле? Или загружать по одной ссылке в главном цикле, и потом также читать эту ссылку во внутреннем цикле?

Comment: и там, и там два цикла